# Using a ID in a variable to show a section of another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a total beginner so this might be a funny question. 
I'm building a small gallery for my portfolio website. 
What I want to get is : after clicking a div with a specific ID, I want to use that Id to get a part of another HTML file with the same ID and put it on the screen. Like a pop-up galery. 
Here is some code I've created just to test what ID I have clicked on.

```
$('.project').click(function(){
    var clickedID = this.id;
    $('.wrapper').load('galery.html ', function (){
        ...
    });
    alert(clickedID);}
);
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: `ids` are uniqe, so when you get an element with the same `id` your html will be invalid.

Comment: As @esibehr said, ids are unique. You may want to use `data` attributes maybe.

Comment: but can I store the information in a variable ? Because when I put is in a variable it is a string right ? that can be used to search for in another html ?

Answer (score 0):

you change code

```
$('.project').click(function(){
var clickedID = this.id;
 $('.wrapper').load('galery.html ', function (){
    alert(clickedID);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
$('.project').click(function(){
 var clickedID = this.id;
 $('.wrapper').load('galery.html #' + clickedId, function (){});
})
```

This will parse the **galery.html** and find the `clickedId` and will insert into `.wrapper`